# PowerShell SQL Server Cannot Find Path

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have 2x mini scripts which are fairly similar.

The first backs up our SQL Jobs and runs fine:

```
Import-Module "SQLPS" Get-ChildItem -Path SQLSERVER:\SQL\MYSERVERNAME\Default\JobServer\Jobs\ | %{$_.script()} | out-file -Filepath "MYFILEPATH_$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).sql"
```

The second is meant to back up our SQL Stored Procedures, and does not produce results in the output file:

```
Import-Module "SQLPS" Get-ChildItem -Path SQLSERVER:\SQL\MYSERVERNAME\Default\Databases\MYDBNAME\StoredProcedures\ | %{$_.script()} | out-file -Filepath "MYFILEPATH_$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).sql"
```

This problematic second script gives the below error:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\MYSERVERNAME\Default\Databases\MYDBNAME\StoredProcedures\' because it does not exist.
```

It used to run successfully until around the time I upgraded to Windows10. Any suggestions on how to correct this second script?

Comment: Unable to reproduce with the [`SqlServer` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/) on W10 1703 and a reachable server and database.

Comment: The reason I mention `SqlServer` is because [`sqlps` is deprecated](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/06/30/sql-powershell-july-2016-update/). I don't recommend using it unless you're in a restricted environment where it's the only option. For starters, `SqlServer` doesn't replicate the annoying habit of `sqlps` of changing the working directory when importing it.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of that. I've flipped to Import-Module "SqlServer" but still get the same "Cannot find path" issue.

Comment: Check more mundane things, like whether `dir SQLSERVER:\SQL\MYSERVERNAME\Default\Databases\ ` lists any databases. There may be an issue with authentication. Also, try `sqlcmd -S MYSERVERNAME -d MYDBNAME -Q "select * from sys.sql_modules"`, you might get a clearer error message.

Comment: I can query tables/views/schemas etc. I only get the error when requesting StoredProcedures. Possibly a bug: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4fcad847-c360-4959-80ae-af47bf89b9a3/powershell-cannot-find-path-storedprocedures-because-it-doesnt-exist?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: And this is why I personally prefer querying over the system catalog to SMO/cmdlets/whatever other beautiful O-O wrapper they come up with... it works on all editions and if there's any problems, I can fix them myself. Anyway, if you're feeling adventurous, you could fire up a profiler and see what queries are ultimately delivered to SQL Server to get the sprocs. There may be some compatibility issue there.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `Invoke-SqlCmd`: `Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance MYSERVERNAME -Database MYDBNAME "select o.[name], m.[definition] from sys.objects o join sys.sql_modules m on m.[object_id] = o.[object_id] where o.[type] = 'P' and o.is_ms_shipped = 0" |% { $_.definition }`. Admittedly not as convenient and no autocomplete, but hey.